# Embedding a Flex Google Map in a WordPress Page

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

I'm embedding a Flex app in a WordPress page using Matt Carpenter's great [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/swfobj/). It's a map created using Google Maps' Flash API.

I'm getting an initialization failure. Is that because the API key is in the Flex app and 
Google can't "see" it?

This is the error that I'm getting:

> Initialization failed: please check
>   the API key, swf location, version and
>   network availability.

Or do I have something else going on? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi J_A_X, Thanks for the help. I made a mistake with the API key. I was testing on my localhost and it worked fine. I then embedded it in a page running on my local machine but on a different host-- hence Google Maps puked. Hope you had a good weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the API key can only be used on 1 domain. Try creating a new key that's specifically to be used for online files. Use the other key you already have for offline testing.

Lewis

Comment: Hi lewi-p, Thanks for the help. You're right I had the wrong API key. Thanks